# Грамматическая основа?

Tags: основа

> Тяжёлыми шапками белого снега покрыты тёмно-зелёные ветви высоких и
> маленьких елей.

Подскажите, какая грамматическая основа в предложении?

Comment: Ответы нужно давать в ответах.

Answer (score 1):

Подлежащее — **ветви** (сущ., мн. ч.), сказуемое — **покрыты** (краткое причастие);
ветви (чего?) *е́лей* (дополнение);
ветви (какие?) *тёмно-зелёные* (определение);
елей (каких?) *высоких, маленьких* (однородные определения);
покрыты (чем?) *шапками* (дополнение);
шапками (какими?) *тяжёлыми* (определение);
шапками (чего?) *сне́га* (дополнение);
снега (какого?) *белого* (определение).