# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "как":

- И я побежал по нему как по канату к соседней крыше.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUpH1t-49DM и сами дайте ответ на вопрос. А мы поправим если что.

Comment: Я тоже ознакомилась с видео по ссылке и могу сказать, что более бездарного изложения темы мне еще не встречалось. Союз КАК универсален, он применяется во многих синтаксических коннструкциях, и, разумеется, все темы  надо анализировать отдельно. Там же в шести пунктах  (запятая ставится/запятая не ставится) изложены сведения, взятые из различных тем совершенно произвольно. И это нам предлагается запомнить?  Я же предлагаю с большей ответственностью относиться к таким "учебным материалам"  даже для себя и уж во всяком случае не рекомендовать его другим людям.

Comment: Что касается вечной проблемы домашних заданий, то она как-то непоследовательно рассматривается. Тема оборотов с союзом КАК  должна иметь особый статус, там нет похожих решений. А вот другие вопросы, которые недавно обсуждались, гораздо больше напоминают ДЗ. Например: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463714/Грамматическая-основа    Основа там очень простая, явное ДЗ, надо бы спросить у автора его мнение. Нет, справшивать не стали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*И я побежал по нему, как по канату, к соседней крыше.*

Это обособленный сравнительный оборот со значением уподобления. Здесь можно использовать союз «словно», который в большей степени говорит нам о художественном приеме сравнения, чем нейтральный союз «как»: *побежал по нему, словно по канату.*

Также можно обратить внимание на то, что при повторе предложных падежных форм (по нему, как по канату) оборот обычно обособляется.

В любом случае это не обстоятельство образа действия, так как оборот расположен на расстоянии от глагола.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с https://rus.stackexchange.com/help и не спешите с ответом.

Comment: Видимо у неё несколько аккаунтов. Обычное дело для интернета...